# how to find php cacti cron job script

Tags: php, cron, snmp, cacti

I have installed cacti php in my ubuntu 14.04.
Cacti create rrd file and periodically update it after each 5 mins.
sample rrd file like  /var/lib/cacti/rra/localhost_hdd_free_14.rrd

I need some help.

Now I want to know this script path that create and update this rrd file in
background.Means, I want to know where this script is located in cacti 
environment.

This peridic update is continue even I stop the apache server.
It means it running as cron job.
But when I run this command "crontab -e -u root"
it says that there is no cron job for this user.

I want to find out how the data is collected across network using snmp
to create graph for different device.

Please help me to find out this cron scipt.

Comment: did you check the other user accounts? jobs shouldn't run as root if they don't have to... maybe it's running as www-user or something.

Comment: yes .It is www-data.I have checked .It says no crontab for www-data.     Here is the command      " crontab -e -u www-data"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here what I  have find.

You can get the list of cronjob running under Linux Ubuntu in following directory.

**`/etc/cron.d/`** directory.

Under this directory,you wll find the all cronjob running for **cacti**.
You can edit desired file if you have permission.
Then do the change what you want like changing interval for cron,changing target file that you want run.